# Parse SQL and replace a parameter in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, parsing

I have a list of insert sql strings throw mysqldump. E.g.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (1, 'wow');
INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (2, 'yeah');
```

I want to import this sql to another service, and add 10 to each sql's id.
I know `PreparedStatement` in `java.sql` can set parameter to sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (？, ？);
```

But how to analyze an existing sql, get and replace a parameter in Java?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (10 + ?, ?);` ?

Comment: `update table set id = id +10 `

Comment: These SQL are generated through mysqldump. I don't have the parameters of each field.

Comment: See [JSqlParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-parsing)

Comment: you can use **str.replace('VALUES (', 'VALUES ( 10 + ')**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how your strings are stored, but as a string replacement, you can do:

```
replace(sql_strings, ", '", " + 10, '")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My sql strings will be more complicated. Using str.replace may not work. I think I should change the way to export my data.